# Quartz Scheduler with Cron not picking all the jobs

Tags: c#, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, crontrigger

I've a windows service that creates and hosts some jobs (today the number is 64, it can go up to 1400) to be executed as different schedules. Out of those 64 that I currently have say 30 should kick off at 4 AM and 4 PM every day, 10 should kick off at 3 AM and 3 PM every day and the remaining 14 should kick off at 5 AM and 5 PM everyday. I see that few of the jobs are being triggered properly according to the schedule and it is leaving several jobs behind and never triggering them.

When I looked at the crons expressions in the QRTZ_ tables and the Next fire time all looks good. I've had the following configurations and the below is my code to create and trigger the schedules. What must be going wrong and how can I figure that out.

```
IJobDetail objJobDet = JobBuilder.Create<AuditProcessor>()
                       .WithIdentity("Job-" + obj.Key.ToString(), AuditType.ToString())
                       .UsingJobData(obj.Key)
                       .Build();

ITrigger objJobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                         .WithIdentity("Trigger-" + obj.Key.ToString(), AuditType.ToString())                            
                         .StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(startAtTime))
                         .WithCronSchedule(objCronExp[obj.Key], x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires())
                         .Build();

QrtzController.AddJobToScheduler(objJobDet, objJobTrigger);
```

Config:

```
<add key="QrtzSchedulerInstanceName" value="SignAuditInstance"/>
<add key="QrtzSchedulerInstanceId" value="SignAuditInstanceOne"/>
<add key="QrtzThreadPoolType" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz"/>
<add key="QrtzthreadCount" value="50"/>
<add key="QrtzThreadPriority" value="Normal"/>

<!--Job Store Properties-->
<add key="QrtZJobStoreMisfireThreshold" value="60000"/>
<add key="QrtzJobStoreType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz"/>
<add key="QrtzJobStoreUseProps" value="false"/>
<add key="QrtzJobStoreDataSource" value="default"/>
<add key="QrtzJobStoreClustered" value="false"/>
```

Comment: What version of quartz are you using? See if this is relevant for you https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-283

Comment: I'm using 2.4.1.0. Issue is same, but that doesn't seem to be working that way though.